# Convert Byte Array to Network Time Protocol [RFC 1305]

Tags: c#, .net, date, time

How can I convert an Byte array to time based on the Network Time Protocol (NTP v3; RFC 1305)

I've found the DateTime method but I think this is based on RFC 1123.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't have time to read through whole RFC 1305
However according to the comment on this [page](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/socket_nist_time_server.asp)

> The time server will send a big-endian 32-bit integer representing
>    the number of seconds since since 00:00 (midnight) 1 January 1900 GMT.

So I think you should use [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and convert your bytes to int and then create a DateTime. Something like this:

```
  var receivedBytes = ReceiveFromTimeServer();
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(receivedBytes);
  var seconds = BitConverter.ToInt32(receivedBytes, 0);
  var date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, seconds);
```